# Notify JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifyjs

I am working on a Notify JS Notification option. I have tried but its not working.  If I remove Style and class name its working fine.

```
   <style>

    .notifyjs-happyblue-base {
      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: lightblue;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .notifyjs-happyblue-superblue {
      color: white;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    </style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="notify.js"></script>
<script src="notify.min.js"></script>  

<script>

        $(function(){
          $.notify("Your Break is Approved", {
            style: 'happyblue',
            className: 'superblue'
            title: "E-Contact Application"
          });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: You need a comma after the class name. i.e. `className: 'superblue',`

Comment: @p.s.w.g I have included comma its not working

Comment: *It's not working* isn't very descriptive. Are you seeing an error or unexpected results? Other than the typo, the only possible issue I can see is that you're importing `notify.js` *and* `notify.min.js` -- typically `x.min.js` is just a minified version of `x.js` so there's no need to include both. I recommend putting a snippet or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) together to demonstrate the issue you're seeing.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include ... a specific problem or error_.

Answer (score 4):

Step one, just include the script once... you are including the uncomprssed version, and the minified version...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="notify.js"></script> DITCH THIS LINE -->
<script src="notify.min.js"></script>
```

Step two, make sure your syntax is correct...

```
$(function(){
    $.notify("Your Break is Approved", {
        style: 'happyblue',
        className: 'superblue', // <-- just a comma, but really important
        title: "E-Contact Application"
    });
});
```

Putting it all together...

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/notify/0.4.2/notify.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.notify.addStyle('happyblue', {
     html: "<div>☺<span data-notify-text/>☺</div>",
     classes: {
        base: {
          "white-space": "nowrap",
          "background-color": "lightblue",
          "padding": "5px"
        },
        superblue: {
          "color": "white",
          "background-color": "blue"
        }
      }
    });


    $.notify("Your Break is Approved", {
        style: 'happyblue',
        className: 'superblue', // <-- just a comma, but really important
        title: "E-Contact Application"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$.notify.addStyle(...` befor `$.notify("Message",...`

```js
$.notify.addStyle('happyblue', {
  html: "<span><span data-notify-text/></span>",
     classes: {
        base: {
          "white-space": "nowrap",
          "background-color": "lightblue",
          "padding": "5px"
        },
        superblue: {
          "color": "white",
          "background-color": "blue"
        }
      }
});

$.notify("Message", {
  style: 'happyblue',
  className: 'superblue'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/notifyjs/notifyjs/master/dist/notify.js"></script>
```